# Is forte pronounced “fort” or “for-tay”?

Tags: pronunciation

How do you pronounce *forte*?  *Fort* or *for-tay*?

Comment: Either is fine. But why are you writing in all caps?

Comment: I'm asking myself while typing the question, the feature **similar questions** didn't display the duplicate? The two titles are identical.

Comment: @only_pro — Is that a deliberate attempt to mislead?

Comment: @David No. What I said is accurate. Both pronunciations are commonly used; therefore, both are correct.

Comment: @only_pro — And I would challenge that, which is one of the reasons why you should do what it says in the comment box and not answer questions there. If you answer as an answer you have to justify your opinion and be prepared to take down votes and criticism, rather than just playing God with the OP.

Comment: @David Ok. Challenge all you want, but there's nothing to argue—just look in the dictionary. I don't care about earning rep or anything else about SE besides helping people. Answering in answers is usually pointless.

Comment: Both ways are correct.  I generally pronounce an "ay" at the end, but some years ago, a girl I knew in Nebraska corrected my pronunciation and said it's supposed to be pronounced the same as the word "fort."  I suspected she might not be wrong because it's obviously a loanword and because I speak Portuguese and in Portuguese, European Portuguese, "forte" is pronounced much like how we pronounce "fort."  So, we looked it up.  It turned out it's pronounced both ways.

Comment: @David - Apparently, the pronunciations of the word "forte" are not your *forte*.

Comment: @only_pro - You're right.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman — I only discuss answers with people who are willing to conform to the format specified by Stack Exchange.

Comment: @David - Yet you are.  What's more, this isn't an answer.  It's a comment.  Also, notably, you did not conform what you put to the format specified by Stack Exchange for answers.  You provide no sources at all, but I do here: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/forte?s=t . That proves you're wrong.  Period.

Comment: I have a 1930s Concise Oxford Dictionary which gives the monosyllabic pronunciation for this sense of the word. However, my 1992 Pocket Oxford gives 'fortay' (in phonetic symbols) for both this and the musical sense.